# The limit of an integral using integrating by part

Tags: integration, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $G(x)$ be the density of $N(0,1)$ random variable. Let $h$ be a function in $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $h$ and $h'$ are both bounded. By integration by part, we have 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} G(x)(h'(x) - xh(x))\ dx = 0
$$
Let $g_n$ be a sequence of piecewise continuous functions such that for every $n$, we have 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g_n(x)\ dx= 1$$
and for every $h$ in $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $h$ and $h'$ are both bounded, we have 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g_n(x)(h'(x) - xh(x))\ dx = 0$$
I'm asked to show that for every bounded continuous function $f$, we have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g_n(x) f(x)\ dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} G(x)f(x)\ dx
$$
I can only guess for the first step that we have 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g_n(x)e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}h(x))'\ dx = 0
$$
and I guess it has some connections to probability theory. But I don't know how to continue. Thanks for any help!